# How to make @OneToOne mapping with filter based on parent's property?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I'm writing an application that has direct and readonly access to a legacy database which initially is used in Ruby on Rails app. The DB is huge, but here is part that I want to make a mapping for in Hibernate.

[image: Data model]

There is a table that has `item_type` field, which is one of `item1`, `item2`, `item3`
And there is also `item_id` field. It depends on the value of the `item_type` field. For example, if `item_type` is `item1`, then `item_id` means ID from `item1` table.
The tables have no foreign keys and are not connected at all.

The question is, how do I make so that `item1`, `item2` and `item3` mapped if and only if the `item_type` is set to the corresponding value. For example, if `item_type` set to `item2`, then `item2` field of `Reference` has reference to the item object and the other two (`item1`, `item3`) are `null`:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@StandardException
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "reference")
class Reference extends PanacheEntity {
    @Column(name = "field_a")
    private String fieldA;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Item1 item1;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Item2 item2;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Item3 item3;

}
```

I tried to use `@JoinColumnOrFormula` + `@JoinFormula` annotation, but it does not seem to be suited for that. `referencedColumnName` must be the column of the `item1` table.  But I need to specify column from `reference` table.

```java
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "'item1'", referencedColumnName = "item_type")),
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
})
private Item1 item1;
```

The other option I tried is `@Where` annotation, like this:

```java
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "item_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@Where(clause = "item_type = 'item1'")
private Item1 item1;
```

But hibernate still assumes that the clause is for the `item` table. It produces wrong sql, where `item_type` is being references from the wrong table, like this:

```sql
select <here goes field list> 
from reference r
join item1 i1 on i1.id = r.item_id 
    and i1.item_type = 'item1' -- wrong! item_type column is in the reference table, not in item1
```

I tried also `@Where(clause = "reference.item_type = 'item1'")` but still no luck, it just ignores the annotation as if it was not there.

Any ideas? Is it doable at all?